# How to extend JSX types for Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote a new component like the following code:

```js
function CustomInput({ floatLabel, ...props }: any) {
  return (
    <label>
      {floatLabel}
      <input {...props} />
    </label>
  );
}
```

I want to provide Typescript IntelliSense for this element (An HTML input + new `floatLabel` attribute )

```js
<CustomInput floatLabel="x" type="input"  /> // I need full IntelliSense for this element.
```

Just like other standard HTML tags.
[image]

How to provide full IntelliSense by extending TS Types as a standard HTML input with a new `floatLabel` attribute for `<CustomInput>`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `{ floatLabel, ...props }: any`. You have to provide type information for the props to the `CustomInput` component.

To get the type information for props of input element as well, you need to add `React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>` in the declaration for the `CustomInput` component.

```js
interface ICustomInputProps {
  floatLabel: string; // the type for value of floatLabel
  // you also have to define type information for other props
}

// To get type info for input props

type TExtendedProps = ICustomInputProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>

function CustomInput({ floatLabel, ...props }: TExtendedProps) {
  return (
    <label>
      {floatLabel}
      <input {...props} />
    </label>
  );
}
```

If you want to use `React.FC` generic

```js
interface ICustomInputProps {
  floatLabel: string; // the type for value of floatLabel
  // you also have to define type information for other props
}

// To get type info for input props

type TExtendedProps = ICustomInputProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>

const CustomInput: React.FC<TExtendedProps> = ({ floatLabel, ...props } => {
  return (
    <label>
      {floatLabel}
      <input {...props} />
    </label>
  );
}
```

Comment: what about HTMLInput attributes? I want `CustomInput` has all HTMLInput attributes too.  With your code `type`, `name` & ... are not valid. I don't want to define everything! I want to be HTMLInput + a new floatLabel attribute.

Comment: We should change the `ICustomInputProps` definition to `interface ICustomInputProps extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement> {
  floatLabel: string;
}`

Comment: There is another way, which is more readable. updated the answer have a look. :)